# help to understand the partial derivative of $f(x,y) = {1 + h(x) \over 1 + (g(y))^2}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Can you please help me to understand how given this function:

$f(x,y) = {1 + h(x) \over 1 + (g(y))^2}$

Its partial derivative is:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = {1 \over 1 + (g(y))^2}(1 + h'(x))$

My initial attempt was:
$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = {1 \over 1 + (g(y))^2}(h'(x))$

Comment: Your answer is correct; what makes you think it might be 1+h'(x)? the '1+' goes away since $\frac{1}{1+g^2(y)}$ is treated as a constant when taking the partial wrt x.

Comment: @zen The solution given by my teacher is what I posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x,y)=\frac{1+h(x)}{1+(g(y))^2}=\underbrace{\frac{1}{1+(g(y))^2}}_{\text{independent of }x}+\underbrace{\frac{1}{1+(g(y))^2}}_{\text{independent of }x}\,h(x)$$

When taking the partial derivative with respect to $x$, you can treat expressions independent of $x$ as constants. Hence

$$f'_x(x,y)=0+\frac{1}{1+(g(y))^2}h'(x)$$

and your attempt is correct.

Comment: I was going crazy trying to reverse engineer my teacher's solution...

Answer (score 0):

The approach I take (and also show to students) is to replace *literally*, either mentally or on paper, any occurrence of a variable or function of a variable which is **not** the one which is involved in the partial differentiation with a constant, say, $ \ C \ . $  This can make it easier to see which portions of the expression will require differentiation and to avoid confusion over how to proceed.  To pull an problem from Stewart (6th Ed., Section 14.3, #36):

$$f(x,y,t,z) \ = \ \frac{xy^2}{t + 2z} \ ; $$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \ = \ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} [ \ \frac{C \cdot y^2}{D} \ ] \ = \ \frac{C}{D} \cdot 2y \ = \ \frac{2xy}{t + 2z} \ ;   $$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \ = \ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} [ \ \frac{C}{D + 2z} \ ] \ = \ \frac{\partial}{\partial z} [ \ C \cdot (D + 2z)^{-1} \ ] $$

$$= \ \ C \cdot (-1) \cdot (D + 2z)^{-2} \cdot 2 \ = \ -\frac{2xy^2}{(t + 2z)^2} \ .   $$

This may seem like a "training-wheels" approach to some, but I find it particularly helpful in getting students to be clear about what partial differentiation does and where to use it in conjunction with the other rules of differentiation, such as the Product, Quotient, and Chain Rules.

For your function, we have

$$f(x,y) \ = \ \frac{1 + h(x)}{1 + [g(y)]^2} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \ = \ \frac{\partial}{\partial x} [ \ \frac{1 + h(x)}{D} \ ] \ = \ \frac{1}{D} \cdot [  \frac{  \partial}{\partial x}h(x) \ ] \   = \  \frac{h'(x)}{1 + [g(y)]^2} \ , $$

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \ = \ \frac{\partial}{\partial y} [ \ \frac{C}{1 + [g(y)]^2} \ ] \ = \ C \cdot   \frac{  \partial}{\partial y} [ \ (1 + [g(y)]^2)^{-1} \ ] $$

$$= \ C \cdot (-1) \cdot (1 + [g(y)]^2)^{-2} \cdot [ \  \frac{  \partial}{\partial y} (1 + [g(y)]^2) \ ] $$

$$= \ C \cdot (-1) \cdot (1 + [g(y)]^2)^{-2} \cdot [ \ 2g \cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial y} g(y) \ ] = \  -\frac{2 \ [ \ 1 + h(x) \ ] \cdot g(y) \cdot g'(y) }{( \ 1 + [g(y)]^2 \ )^2}  \ , $$

with the primes in each expression representing differentiation by the appropriate variable.